# Robot Framework with Pycharm -- Autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I've installed PyCharm with the `robotframework` support plugin.
The .robot files are identified successfully and I was able to create a simple script and run it in pyCharm.

However, my problem is that no keywords nor even the `robotframework` libraries (selenium2library) are recognized by pycharm in order to be autocompleted when typing them.

I also have the `intellibot` plugin installed.

Is there something that I'm missing? Is there another configuration file somewhere?

Thanks,

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also have the intellibot plugin installed.

Comment: configure pycharm .....follow this link http://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/10/11/configuring-pycharm-to-run-tests.html

Comment: I already did that; but that is only for running robot scripts. My problem is when I develop the scripts.. no autocomplete :|

Comment: is your project in a virtual env?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set up your Library to `robotframework-selenium2library == 1.8.0`, then the issue will disappear.

If you have the last version it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

1. Uninstall the 'Robot framework support' (PyCharm/File/Settings/Plugins)
2. Uninstall 'Intellibot' (PyCharm/File/Settings/Plugins) (Uninstall all similar plugins!)
3. Exit PyCharm
4. Uninstall robotframework-seleniumlibrary (Open command prompt with administration mode: `pip uninstall robotframework-seleniumlibrary`)
5. Install robotframework-seleniumlibrary 3.3.1 (Command prompt: `pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.3.1`)
6. Open PyCharm
7. Install 'IntelliBot @SeleniumLibrary Patched' (PyCharm/File/Settings/Plugins)

(If it isn't working then try the following: PyCharm/File/Invalidate Caches/Restart... and click the 'Invalidate and Restart')

Comment: I did this except for the first step (uninstall "robot framework support") because it wasn't installed in my project. I went to File > Settings > Project:myproject > Python interpreter and added selenium, robotframework and then robotframework-seleniumlibrary (the latter needs to be 3.3.1 version or whatever version you installed with pip). Restarted pycharm and got autocomplete working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the intellibot plugin.
To resolve you need to 
1. Uninstall your current intellibot plugin 
2. Search for "IntelliBot @SeleniumLibrary Patched" in the plugins repository.
3. Install this patched plugin.
This worked for me.

Comment: Installed the "IntelliBot @SeleniumLibrary Patched" and still not working

Answer (score 1):

You can try install "Robot Framework support" plugin.
it working for me.

Answer (score 0):

use plugin Intellbot@SeleniumLibrary Patched
and robotframework-seleniumlibrary version 3.3.1
It works for me after lot of research from the internet

Answer (score 0):

I recomend to use lte2000 fork: https://github.com/lte2000/intellibot

It works fine for me (`Pycharm 2020.1`, `Robot Framework 3.2.2` and `SeleniumLibrary 4.5.0`)

Answer (score 0):

In our main_resources.robot we need to give file path as below for the library files which contain definition of function

Library           ../lib/SampleRest/SampleRest.py

When you do cntl+click on above SampleRest.py it should be navigated to that file

Your SampleRest.py should contain all your function definitions as below

```py
try:
    from .api import *
except:
    from api import *


class SampleRest(
    events,
    repository,
    devices
):
    """
    This library will provides keywords to automating the cloud test cases
    """
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = 1.0

    def __init__(self):
        for base in SampleRest.__bases__:
            base.__init__(self)
```

Once I declare this I can use any of functions present in above devices.py file from robot file and it will be successfully navigated
Also please check your robotframework-seleniumlibrary version it should be 3.3.1 because for latest version navigation is an issue

Answer (score 0):

I have been troubled by this for what seems to be forever.

Here are my configuration steps, and so far everything is working like a charm.

My setup:

- Installed Python 3.9.x => added path to variables in "windows environment Variables" Check python and pip versions.
- install selenium
- install robotframework
- install robotframework-seleniumlibrary
- Install Pycharm and set Interpreter to Python 3.9.x
- Install Plugin: "IntelliBot @SeleniumLibrary Patched"  - Do not install Selenium2Library This is what causes the IDE issues.
- Restart IDE and enjoy. And for those just getting into Robotframework, dont forget to add webdrivers.

For this I made a folder in root (called it webdrivers) and also added this to my Windows Enviro variables. This allows me to call them from any project folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am going through the same problems... I've tried IntelliBot, IntelliBot #patched, Robot Framework Support plugins.
Now I am testing the `Hyper RobotFramework Support` plugin [[link]](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16382-hyper-robotframework-support) and for now, looks the best from all of these.

With it I have some auto-complete support, also ctrl+click (navigation) works nice (better than in IntelliBot). Not perfect, but the best it has been so far.

I have installed:

- PyCharm 2021.3.2
- Python 3.10.2
- Robot Framework 4.1.3
- selenium 4.1.3
- robotframework-seleniumlibrary 6.0.0

(on windows you can run the command `pip list` to see the version of the libraries that have been installed using pip)

[image: Hyper RobotFramework Support]