# Pycharm with Robot Framework - Intellisense not working

Tags: selenium, pycharm, robotframework

I'm trying to write a simple UI automation using robot framework and I'm using PyCharm IDE for that. But in the IDE, intellisense are not working.
I've already installed the "IntelliBot @SeleniumLibrary Patched" plugin.

[image]

I'm using following versions.

- PyCharm Community 2019.3 version
- Python 3.8.1
- pip 20.0.2
- Robot Framework 3.1.2

I uninstalled and re installed all of the above(python, PyCharm etc...) and restarted the PC but no luck.
Also tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196953/robot-framework-with-pycharm-autocomplete-doesnt-work/54354095) and those solutions also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using "[Robot Framework Support plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyOrI.png)" It works like charm with my setup for UI automation with Robot Framework.